# Showing SO(n) is a compact topological group for every n

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show that SO(n) is a compact topological group for every n. Some introductory info: SO(n) is the group of all nxn matrices M such that $M^{T}M = I$ and $det(M)=1$. I have a hint that says to show that SO(n) is a bounded, closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$. The columns of an element of SO(n) are all vectors of length 1. I'm trying to understand this first for $n=2$. I think I understand the bounded part. If $n=2$, then all the elements in SO(2) are all contained in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ vectors of length 2, so bounded. Not sure how to get closed. I have this loose image in my mind that elements of SO(2) are including their boundary so to speak, but I'm not sure how to make this rigorous.

Comment: The mappings $M\mapsto M^TM$ and $M\mapsto \det M$ are both continuous. The inverse images of singletons are closed, because _______.

Comment: Oh, they're continuous because they both map to the identity. Thus by DeMorgan's law, the preimages for both $M's$ will be $SO(2)$.

Comment: No, a function does not get to be continuous because you are looking at a certain value. Think carefully and critically.

Comment: Because take for example the first M map. $M^{-1}(U)= SO(2)$ if $I \in U$ or the empty set otherwise for open sets U in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. Those are both open in the subspace topology of $SO(2)$. Thus preimage of open is open, so continuous. Now by DeMorgan's we get the preimage of closed is closed, so $SO(2)$ is closed, yeah?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices, which topologically is the same as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. If you define $L,R:\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ by $L(M)=M^tM$ and $R(M)=MM^t$ you will see that both are continuous. Because if you expand $MM^t$ and $M^tM$ multiplications you will see that these are just sophisticated polynomials, that's all. Similarly $det:\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ function is continuous, as all polynomials are.

Then

$$SO(n)=\{M\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\ |\ MM^t=M^tM=Id\text{ and }det(M)=1\}$$
can be rewritten as
$$SO(n)=L^{-1}(\{Id\})\cap R^{-1}(\{Id\})\cap det^{-1}(\{1\})$$

and therefore it is closed, as finite intersection of preimages (through continuous functions) of closed subsets.

Note that the same is true if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$, or any other topological ring.